# writing a junit test(s) for a method that returns boolean and accepts two params of non-primitive type

Tags: if-statement, junit, multiple-conditions

I am fairly new to writing Junits in such detail.

The method
returns boolean true/false
accepts two params of same non-primitive type.

This method does a whole lot of validations by comparing the two instances of the similar type using if else conditions.
And few more validations while iterating through the collection based fields of the params .

I tried writing the base scenario, but unclear as to how to do it for the underlying if_conditons. especially with regard to mocking the data.

What I tried and aware: There are lots of methods under AssertClass which I can use to validate, however for this method that return boolean based on quite a bunch of conditions, how do I write? do I have to write individual asserts for each condition under the @Test annotated method?
below is my code :

```
public boolean checkEligblity(A newversion, A currentversion) {
    if (currentversion.getPurchaseOrders().isEmpty())
        return true;
    if (currentversion.getReceiptNotice() != newversion.getReceiptNotice()
            || currentversion.getSizeType() != newversion.getSizeType()
            || currentversion.getNumInPrices() != newversion.getNumInPrices())
        return true;
    boolean storeM = newversion.getReceiptNotice() == PASSED;
    if (currentversion.getOrderInfo() != newversion.getOrderInfo()) {
        if (storeM || containsCustomerString(currentversion.getOrderInfo())
                || containsCustomerString(newversion.getOrderInfo()))
            return true;
    }
    List<PurchaseOrders> newVersionPurchaseOrders = newversion.getPurchaseOrders();
    List<PurchaseOrders> currentVersionPurchaseOrders = currentversion.getPurchaseOrders();
    for (Iterator<PurchaseOrders> newPOIterator = newVersionPurchaseOrders.iterator(); newPOIterator.hasNext();) {
        PurchaseOrders newPO = newPOIterator.next();
        for (Iterator<PurchaseOrders> currentPOIterator = currentVersionPurchaseOrders.iterator(); currentPOIterator
                .hasNext();) {
            PurchaseOrders currentPO = currentPOIterator.next();
            if (newPO.getSku() == currentPO.getSku()
                    && newPO.getSkuId() == currentPO.getSkuId()
                    && newPO.getOrgin() == currentPO.getOrgin()
                    && newPO.getTarget() == currentPO.getTarget()
                    && newPO.getShippingDate()== currentPO.getDepratureDate()) {
                if (currentPO.getStatusCode().equals(newPO.getStatusCode())
                        && currentPO.getItemsInQty().equals(newPO.getItemsInQty())
                        && currentPO.getVendorId().equals(newPO.getVendorId())
                        && currentPO.getCodeInd().equals(newPO.getCodeInd())
                        && currentPO.getPriceType().charAt(0) == newPO.getPriceType().charAt(0)) {
                    boolean matchingFound = true;
                    if (storeM && currentPO.getInbound() != newPO.getInbound()) {
                        matchingFound = false;
                    }
                    if (matchingFound) {
                        newPOIterator.remove();
                        currentPOIterator.remove();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (!newVersionPurchaseOrders.isEmpty() || !currentVersionPurchaseOrders.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
private boolean containsCustomerString(String ticketingInfo) {
    if (orderInfo == null)
        return false;
    if (orderInfo.startsWith(PASS))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You could have a look at property based testing with libraries like [jqwik](https://github.com/jlink/jqwik) but you need to spend some time for learning this type of testing.

Comment: Thank you for  responding, @StefanBirkner .Can it be done anything simpler than that? just using Junit5

Comment: You can write a lot of test where you change one value each time and find out whether the outcome is ok. That's "easier" because you don't have to learn a new technique but it is "harder" because you end up with a lot of test that you have to organise properly.

Comment: @StefanBirkner Right !! I ended up writing a lot of  tests, and that's true I see that already that it's going to be harder to maintain.